# filling up a login form using mechanize , python

Tags: python, forms, autocomplete, mechanize, autologin

I was trying to login to a site https://everest.ioe.edu.np/lanusers/dialup.php  and then click on a 'change password' link , change the password and logout using mechanize with following piece of code :

```
import mechanize        

def tryinglogin():
    browser = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
    browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    r = browser.open("https://everest.ioe.edu.np/lanusers/dialup.php") #surfing web page
    browser.select_form(nr=0)               # Find first form of web page
    browser.form["name"] = "067bce001"
    browser.form["password1"] = "abc"    
    pass="password1"
    browser.submit()                    # submit

    html = browser.response().readlines()       # Read the response, html 
    for i in range(0,len(html)):
    if '<u>Your current LAN account status</b>' in html[i]:  # filter    out one line 
        print(html[i])


    browser.find_link(text='Change password')
    req = browser.click_link(text='Change password')
    browser.open(req)
#print browser.response().read()     #print html of logged in page

  r = browser.open(req)                #  surfing web page ,no problem upto here in code
  browser.select_form(nr=0)             
  browser.form["password"] = "abc"
  browser.form["password1"] = "bcdef"  # change password field  
  browser.form["password2"] = "bcdef"   #verify password field
  browser.submit()      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tryinglogin()
```

the code succesfully logs in , clicks change password link , and goes to change password page but then shows 
    "ParseError: nested FORMs Error"

please gurus help me figure out why my bot is not working.

Comment: Seems like the website's HTML is invalid. You might have better luck just recording the POST request that your browser sends when you log in and then sending it yourself with `requests` or `urllib2`.

Comment: Sir , the code successfully logs in  using given username(067bce001) and password(abc) . There's no error in login page , so , where particularly you are indicating error in html ?

Comment: The HTML error is in the change password page.  Apparently there is a form nested within a form which is invalid.